Seeking formula to continue multiplying until a specified addition number is met
Using the data from the chart (see table below), I need to create a new chart to continue adding up line-by-line totals divided by subtotals until 40 hours' worth of dollars is added up. This is Google Sheets, but many Excel formulas translate. I am also open to using Apps Scripts.
This is my data right now:



rate
hours (quantity)
hours x rate




$0.00
0
$0.00


$35.00
15
$525.00


$40.00
0
$0.00


$50.00
40
$2,000.00



0
$0.00



0
$0.00



0
$0.00



0
$0.00


Total:
55
$2,525.00



The new chart should look similar to that, but the total number of hours should be capped at 40.
This can also be reflected in the hours quantity counting, and I have a formula for that. To get the original chart numbers, I am using
=IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE($J3:$J30)),0)

with J referencing data elsewhere on the sheet.
Right now, this formula produces "$0", which is not helpful:
=IF(SUM($B$33:$B$36) <40, SUMPRODUCT($A36*$B36),0)

I've also used this formula in other parts of the spreadsheet, but it's not what I needed here:
=IF($S$3 > $Q$3,40, IF($Q$3 >= $S$3, SUM($O4:$O$16)))

The expected output is:



base rate
base hours
base hours x rate




$0.00
0
$0.00


$35.00
15
$525.00


$40.00
0
$0.00


$50.00
25
$1,250.00



Note: I'm not looking for "Count" formulas.

https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Please add expected output for the given input.

Use REDUCE to loop over the hours column(B2:B15), while checking the previous accumulator's, sum of hours(hereafter, sh) in every iteration. IF sh of accumulator+current value is less than 40, return the STACKed accumulator and current  hours value(extended to the Left to get base rate column too), else, return the previous accumulator and the 40-sh of previous hours. Finally, use QUERY to get product of hours and base rates
=LET(
  sh,LAMBDA(a,SUM(INDEX(a,,2))),
  exL, LAMBDA(a, OFFSET(a,0,-1,1,2)),
  arr, REDUCE(A2:B2,B3:B15,
    LAMBDA(a,c,
     IF(40-sh(a)-c<=0,
      {a;INDEX(exL(c),1),40-sh(a)},
      VSTACK(a,exL(c))))),
  QUERY(arr,"Select Col1, Col2, Col1*Col2 where Col1 is not null"))


Thanks for this response. I'm holding out for a formula, since a code will slow down the sheets. As a last resort, I will plug this in! Thanks again.

@ArtisFun This is a formula :)
